# Selenium test fails when using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, automated-tests, ui-automation, robotframework

I'm using robot framework with selenium2library to make some tests, Here is my test file :

```
*** Settings ***

Library Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***

${URL_LOCATION}     http://localhost:9000/apps/depot/#
${BROWSER_TYPE}     chrome

*** Test Cases ***

Open browser to DEPOT page

    Open Browser     ${URL_LOCATION}
    Click Element    xpath=//div[@class="btn action xlarge nav-next"]
```

The problem is that after making the first step "Open Browser" successfully, the second step fails and I can't understand why...

Here is part of the page that proves that the element exists :

```
 <div class='block action-block'>
    <div class='btn action xlarge nav-next'>{{t step.next.caption }}
 </div>
```

Thanks...

Comment: How does it fail? What error do you get? Is this html inside an iframe?

Comment: The error is : "ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//div[@class="btn action xlarge nav-next"]' did not match any elements."
And it is not inside an iframe only divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that short page snippet, it is hard to tell. But I would try the following:

- Use `Wait Until Element Is Visible` prior to clicking the element. Use `Set Selenium Timeout` to set the timeout for this appropriately. You should get at least a better error message.
- Use Firefox console (or similar in other browsers) to verify your Xpath expression.
- Use an Xpath expression relative to some other element. Something like `//div[@class='block action-block']/div`
- Execute some Javascript directly. If there is some element with id e.g., you could call something like this `Execute Javascript  document.getElementById("parent").children[0].click()`
- Try other click-commands like `Click Button`. I recently had an issue that `Click Element  locator` did not work but `Click Link  linkname` did.

Finally in my experience I would always use single quotes in Xpath expressions. But I guess this is not the problem here.

Comment: It has single quotes.